# How in Deploy configuration to create an artifact dependency? And prescribe a rule for artifacts?

Tags: teamcity

I have two Build Configurations: 1. Bulid. 2. Deploy. In Build pointed folder with artifacts (http://prntscr.com/enws67). And in Deploy the dist folder is taken and moved to the server using rsync (the bash script is already written: http://prntscr.com/enwtzr).

( When I created the build steps from the same Build configuration, in the step where I needed to just deploy the site using the script I specified in the Command Line: C: \ cygwin64 \ bin \ bash.exe / cygdrive / c / cygwin64 / home / Team / Startsync.bash )

The idea is that the rules are set in the configuration, which generates artifacts (Build) and the configuration that consumes them (Deploy)
And thus one configuration can transfer other files.

How in Deploy configuration to create an artifact dependency? And prescribe a rule for artifacts? 
Thanks you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the configuration of the artifacts, at the end download them and they are displayed in artifacts

In the Deploy configuration, go to Edit Configuration Settings -> Dependencies -> Add new artifact dependency

Depend on: specify Build configuration

Artifacts rules: * write rules

+: One =>.
-: second
+: Says to include folder one for download to the folder checkout.directory/

-: - excludes second folder

= = Refers to checkout.directory